# id is not iterable in react map,

Tags: reactjs

I have a React application and in it a component that displays data in a table. I am interested in displaying some things, including id, but not the whole thing, but only the first 5 characters. I try to display in the following way, and get an error `id is not iterable`. What can be done to solve this?

```js
const sliceId = (id) => {
  const idCat = [...id].slice(0,5);
  return idCat
}
```

in return:

```
clientList.map( (el, i) => (
  <tr key={i} >
    <td style={styleTd}>{ ...sliceId(el._id)}</td>
    { /* ... */ }
  </tr>
))
```

Comment: Start by console logging `id` as first line inside `sliceId` and seeing what it actually is? If it was a string, your syntax would work (but also super weird), so check what you're actually getting.

Comment: `id.substring(0,5);`

Comment: @M0nst3R note that if `id` was a string, the destructuring _would_ work (even if it's super weird to use that), so your suggestion alone will still lead to an error, just `id.substring is not a function` instead.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, that is weird indeed. `id` must be undefined or null then.

Comment: Also on a React note: [never use array position as key](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key). The whole point of the `key` attribute is that it uniquely identifies _the thing itself_ so that if elements move around in your array React knows that they moved and can do the same in the DOM, instead of completely rewriting things even though nothing needs rewriting.

Comment: @M0nst3R that'd be `can't access property Symbol.iterator of undefined/null`, it's more likely that `id` is a number or an object (and given the name, almost certainly the former)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's not what my Chrome is saying. I tried both inside a variable `a` and it spits out `Uncaught TypeError: a is not iterable`.

Comment: Ah, sounds like Chrome's playing a little fast and loose with errors then. All the more important for the op to do some debugging.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Please consider not sharing falsy/misleading information, using key as index is fine if only the array is not getting filtered or sorted between renders.

Comment: Just because it's "not going to go wrong if we don't reorder the array" doesn't mean it's fine: get in the habit of using values that uniquely identify each item as key. Even if you're not filtering or sorting "now", don't bake future problems into your current code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans As I mentioned above - please consider avoiding misleading information. Using `index` as a key is fine in most cases. Don't overcomplicate lives.

Comment: And I will direct you to the, also mentioned above, official React documentation which all but tells you not to do so and use proper keys, including calling out the issue of array indices using a giant "pittfal" warning box. Don't promote bad habits, teach people to use proper keys. It's _barely_ any effort for someone to write `item.id` or `item.name` or even `item.creation_date` if that's guaranteed unique, instead of using `i`.

Answer (score 0):

For me in the end this is the code that worked:

```
 <td style={styleTd}>{el._id.substring(3,8)}</td>
```

The problem was that I had an initialState that was a different type and not a String.
Thanks to you I solved, thank you.